# Trying to do margin mirroring in iTextPDF

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I'm formatting a pdf for a book using iTextPDF 5.5.13.3 in Java and it's working great. I'm trying to create a gutter for the book by using the margin mirroring feature. It seems simple enough, but is not working. Here's my code that is executed as soon as the Document is created:

```
   document.setMargins(15,      // left
                       30,      // right
                       15,      // top
                       25);     // bottom

  document.setMarginMirroring(true);
```

(BTW, don't pay attention to the units, I'm specifying them in mm)

The left/right margins are different so that there will be extra room to bind the book. I expect that the left/right margins will magically swap on alternate pages because of the setMarginMirroring, but it doesn't happen. Instead, the initial margins are used throughout the document.

What am I doing wrong?